# compare variables value with an exception logic

Tags: javascript

I have a variable with values as below and a less than equal operation is compared between them, except that when it contains zero.

Zero is of highest priority every time.

```
if(a<=b){
alert("a is lesser"); 
} else{
alert("b is higher");
}
```

How do I include condition for zero value i.e.. if b contains value as zero the condition should alert b is higher.

Comment: if(b ==0){ } else { } ?

Comment: `b != 0 && a <= b`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your condition to be false when `b` is `0` by adding `.. && b != 0`:

```
if( a<=b && b!=0 ){
    alert("a is lesser"); 
} else {
    alert("b is higher");
}
```

This means if `b == 0` then it will force the condition to be `false` and run the `else`.